# Assigning a Property to a Function Reference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following constructor:

```
function myObject(){
    this.age = 43;
    this.getAge = function(){
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

I create a new object with it

```
myInstance = new myObject();
```

Then assign the getAge method to a variable reference

```
myReference = myInstance.getAge;
```

*this* from the original constructor function now refers to myReference.  I then add the following

```
myReference.age = 99;
```

But when I run myReference(), the browser returns undefined.  I ran the following to debug

```
console.log(myReference)
```

And only see the getAge function; the age property is not present.  Why is the myReference.age assignment not being applied?

Comment: @Sushanth-- in this case, the value of "myReference" *is* an object. It's the function "getAge".

Comment: @Pointy. Thanks for pointing it out.. I used the wrong wordings to phrase it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run your "myReference" function, you're running it without any context.  Therefore, in the function the value of `this` will either be the global context (`window`) or `undefined`.

If you do this:

```
console.log( myReference.call(myReference) );
```

you'd get 99. That's because you'd be explicitly telling the runtime system to call the function with `this` set to the function itself. You could also do this:

```
myReference.getAge = myReference;
console.log( myReference.getAge() );
```

That should also work. Of course, this is a fairly confusing way to do things, and it's not really idiomatic JavaScript.  The thing to note is that `this` is determined by the way a function is *called*, not how the function is *defined*. Also, `this` generally has nothing to do with the function itself unless you do something to arrange that (and that's kind-of weird).

You could also use `.bind` to create a bound version of the "getAge" function. If you want a function bound to the instance (which I think makes sense), you'd do this:

```
var myReference = myInstance.getAge.bind( myInstance );
```

Now setting the "age" property on "myReference" won't affect the property on the instance:

```
myReference.age = 99;
console.log( myReference() ); // logs 49
```

But setting the property on the *instance* will:

```
myInstance.age = 99;
console.log( myReference() ); // logs 99
```

Comment: Thanks, anyway to incorporate the native JS bind function with this instead of using the call method so as not to execute myReference immediately?

Comment: @LloydBanks I'm not sure I completely understand your question but I'll add a paragraph about `bind`.

Comment: I was actually a bit more interested as to whether I could bind in the following fashion: ***myReference = myInstance.getAge.bind(myReference);***, effectively changing ***this*** to reference myReference.  I played around with the above, but get a myReference is not defined error.